# How to replace string in JSON format in Javascript with data from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

For a site that I'm making, I wanted to have an additional feature which uses this plugin on GitHub called [cratedigger](https://github.com/risq/cratedigger) that uses WebGL and Three.js. It is a 3D virtual crate that contains vinyl records, and simulates "crate digging" of albums. The plugin gets the data for the vinyl titles, artists, and covers through a string in JSON format that is parsed through JSON and stored in a const variable. The original code (index.js):

```
    const data = JSON.parse('[{"title":"So What","artist":"Miles 
    Davis","cover":"http://cdn- 
    images.deezer.com/images/cover/63bf5fe5f15f69bfeb097139fc34f3d7/400x400- 
   000000-80-00.jpg","year":"2001","id":"SOBYBNV14607703ACA","hasSleeve":false},
    {"title":"Stolen Moments","artist":"Oliver Nelson","cover":"http://cdn- 
   images.deezer.com/images/cover/99235a5fbe557590ccd62a2a152e4dbe/400x400- 
   000000-80-00.jpg","year":"1961","id":"SOCNMPH12B0B8064AA","hasSleeve":false},
    {"title":"Theme for Maxine","artist":"Woody Shaw","cover":"http://cdn- 
   images.deezer.com/images/cover/bb937f1e1d57f7542a64c74b13c47900/400x400- 
   000000-80-00.jpg","year":"1998","id":"SOMLSGW131343841A7","hasSleeve":false}]
    ');
```

You can view the source code [here](https://github.com/risq/cratedigger/blob/master/src/index.js). The above code is in line 3.

For my site though, I want the titles, artists, covers, etc. to come from my MySQL database. So what I did is when I click a button found in my main site, it will run the sql query of my database and then convert it into a .json file:

```
     //getdatabase.php
        <?php
        include 'includes/session.php';
        include 'includes/header.php';

            $conn = $pdo->open();
            $data = $conn->query("
            SELECT name as title,
            artist_name as artist,
            concat('http://website.com/images/', photo) as cover,
            year(date_created) as year,
            id,
            hasSleeve
            from products
            where category_id = '5';
            ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach($data as &$row){
                $row['hasSleeve'] = filter_var($row['hasSleeve'], 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
            }

            $json_string = json_encode($data);

            $file = 'cratedigger.js/src/htdocs/data.json';
            file_put_contents($file, $json_string);

            $pdo->close();
            header('location: cratedigger.js/lib/index.html');

         ?>
```

Afterwards, it will be redirected to the index of the cratedigger plugin. To retrieve the data in the .json file, I used fetch API in the index.js file under the src folder of this plugin. So I replaced the original code in the plugin with this:

```
    //replaced the long line of const data=JSON.parse('[{"title":...]'); with 
   this:
    let data = [];

    fetch('data.json').then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
     })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);  //outputs data from my database
        return data;
     });

    console.log(data);  //output is 0 or none
```

I use node.js to build and test this plugin, and when I test it with the code I used, the crate appears but with no records in it (a blank wooden crate). In the console, the log inside the fetch api does output the data from the json file, but the log outside the fetch outputs zero or none. I figured that it was that fetch is *asynchronous*, so the second console.log didn't output any data because it didn't wait for fetch to finish.

[image: How it looks like]

And that's my problem. I want to replace the original code that uses a string in JSON format, and replace it with data from my database. Some of the solutions that I came up with that didn't work are:

- Use await and async - This is still asynchronous so it couldn't store my data in the variable.
- XMLHttpRequest is mostly asynchronous too and its synchronous part is already deprecated.
- Place fetch inside a function - My problem with this code is that the variable "data" used in the original code is used/called in other parts of the source files like these examples:

```
    function fillInfoPanel(record) {
      if (record.data.title) {
        titleContainer.innerHTML = record.data.title;
      }
    }

    //or this//
    cratedigger.loadRecords(data, true, () => {
      bindEvents();
    });
```

So calling a function like `myData();` to get the data from fetch wouldn't work as I need it to be inside the `data` variable. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to replace `data` variable used in other parts of the code with a function.

Any suggestions that might work? I don't necessarily need to use fetch to retrieve data. I'm more into HTML, PHP & CSS, and not that familiar with Javascript, so I'm stuck here. Node.JS was something that I've learned a week ago so the codes initially confused me. I've read articles and watched YouTube tutorials about javascript, json, etc. but they confused me more than help with my problem.

Comment: You need to initialize the plugin in `then()` of `fetch()` ... when you actually have the data

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. Do you mean I do this: `fetch('data.json', data = [ ])` or something else. I'm not that familiar with fetch.

Comment: `fetch('data.json').then(function(resp) {return resp.json();}).then(function(data) { initializeMyDigger(data) })`. I made that function name up...you need to create it ...or just do all the initialization right in the `then()` instead of creating function

Comment: @charlietfl I tried it but it comes with this error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: initializeMyDigger is not defined`. So I defined it with this `function initializeMyDigger(){};` above the fetch code, and the error is gone, but no albums still appear.

Comment: Right but that's where you would take the data in and initialize the code needed for your plugin to work